# Is there an app that will take spreadsheet data and turn it into a conceptual map diagram?

Tags: spreadsheet, mind-mapping

I am working on a project where I am connecting various pieces of data, such as this:

- Artists
- Record Labels
- Spotify Playlists
- Venues
- Social Media Channels

The thing is that, these data are often related. For example, an artist is probably associated with a social media page, a record label is often owned or managed by an artist, a spotify playlist is also often curated by an artist, etc...

Currently there is 1 spreadsheet with different tabs each with these categories of data. I'm looking for a program/app that can take this, figure out the associations and create a type of map diagram so that if I click on an artist, it links that artist to venues, social media, labels they are associated with, and likewise if I click on (or scroll to) a venue, it shows me associated artists, etc... This should all be possible from the spreadsheet data itself because I have entered these connections in columns. Is there an app that can do this out of the box? THere is one I saw called Obsidian, but it cannot handle tabular data yet... I believe what I am looking for is called a "mind map".

Comment: Hi. You should post on Logseq and Obsidian forums to see if plugins to convert csv file of your spreadsheet. Logseq has a graph view. E.g. see https://discuss.logseq.com/t/import-from-a-spreadsheet-into-logseq-each-row-a-page-as-outline-not-as-tables-one-time-automated-linking/4620  and also https://unofficial-logseq-docs.gitbook.io/unofficial-logseq-docs/beginner-to-advance-features/tables

Comment: Soudns like a job for https://www.tableau.com/ - whcih is costly . See also https://alternativeto.net/software/tableau/?license=free

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a continuation of my comment, as long. I believe this is something explore.

You should explore [Logseq](https://logseq.com/).

- There is a way to convert a csv file or table e.g. https://unofficial-logseq-docs.gitbook.io/unofficial-logseq-docs/beginner-to-advance-features/tables and https://discuss.logseq.com/t/import-from-a-spreadsheet-into-logseq-each-row-a-page-as-outline-not-as-tables-one-time-automated-linking/4620
- It has mindmap plugins e.g. https://github.com/vipzhicheng/logseq-plugin-mark-map

It also has an in-built graph view.

I use Logseq but not tried this yet.